# Is DirectX 12 development now available to the public?

Tags: c++, directx, directx-12

With Windows Technical Preview build 10074, `D3D12.dll`, `d3d12SDKLayers.dll` and `d3d12warp.dll` are included in `%WINDIR%\System32`. With `Visual Studio 2015 RC` with `Tools for Windows 10` (aka Windows Kits 10 - 10069), `d3d12.lib`, `d3d12.h` etc. are included. Although there seems to be no press release from Microsoft about its availability, the inclusion of these would seem to indicate that is is now available. Is this correct reasoning, or is something else required?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can begin developing DirectX 12 applications using the resources you described above. The API itself is not yet complete and the GPU drivers available are not yet of a final shipping quality, so do not be surprised if not everything is fully functional or bug free. Try and validate your application against more than one manufacturer's GPU and also against the WARP driver if you encounter problems.

Preliminary documentation is available on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn903821(v=vs.85).aspx)